# The root partition changes into 2 partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, overlay

I'm using Deepin OS, yesterday I've updated my Deepin OS to the lates version.

After the latest update (April 2, 2019) my root directory was divided into two partitions (4 GB and 49 GB) like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzUU8.png (the original root partition is 49 GB)

But,the contents of both partitions are the same, here are the details:

- list directory of 4GB partition https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkQOG.png
- list directory of 49GB partition https://i.stack.imgur.com/No5dI.png

It's strange, I don't know why this happened.

Has anyone experienced the same thing? How to fixed this?

I have already asked in the Deepin EN official forum, but have not yet received an answer -> https://bbs.deepin.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=176438&extra=page%3D1

=============

## EDIT / UPDATE

Here's the `mount` result:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3983936k,nr_inodes=995984,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=802288k,mode=755)
/dev/sda6 on /media/root-ro type ext4 (ro,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered)
tmpfs-root on /media/root-rw type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
overlayroot on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/media/root-ro,upperdir=/media/root-rw//overlay,workdir=/media/root-rw//overlay-workdir)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=37,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=2737)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda3 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=802284k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sda5 on /media/newbie95/Data Center type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda4 on /media/newbie95/3A4AC0AA4AC0646B type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda2 on /media/newbie95/System-W10 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda7 on /media/newbie95/7bb8eb64-3e13-44c6-8efe-146cc4e5874b type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
upterm on /tmp/.mount_TyYZCN type fuse.upterm (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Any help will be very appreciated, man. Thankyou :)

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the output of `mount`.

Comment: hi @KamilMaciorowski , here's the `mount` result http://txt.do/15by2

Comment: Best added to the question itself, instead of putting a link to it

Comment: hi @xenoid , sure, I've edited my question above, thankyou for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be somehow entered overlay-root mode by accident, you can try `sudo overlayroot-disable` to restore normal mode.

Note: that may cause data lose, you need to back up the data you created recently.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/dev/sda6` is mounted read only (notice all the padlocks on the original drive). This sometimes happens with minor disk corruption. Did you shutdown, logged out, canceled or powered off in the middle of some part of an update? I would launch a recovery disk (live CD should do) and do a disk check (`sudo e2fsck /dev/sda6`), also check that the `/dev/sda6` entry in `/etc/fstab` is `rw`, then restart.

If they don't work, do a `sudo df -h`, check that you aren't above 95% disk usage (49 is very close to 95% of 54G). Root partitions don't like no space. Get rid of old logs and cached files in `/var/log` or `/var/cache`.